# Name of integration technique where product term is near constant over the interval?

Tags: integration, approximate-integration

Consider

$$\int_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta+\epsilon} g(x)f(x) dx$$

where f(x) is near constant on the interval $(\theta-\epsilon, \theta+\epsilon)$, and g(x) is not. It follows:

$$\int_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta+\epsilon}  g(x)f(x) dx \approx f\left(\theta\right)\int_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta+\epsilon}  g(x) dx$$

I can't find reference to this technique, is this valid? Is there maybe a better way to express this? Maybe some quadrature rule I've missed?

Comment: It's only true if in addition $g(x)$ doesn't vary too much. You are just approximating $f(x)$ by whatever the nearly constant value is; I don't think this estimate by itself is significant enough that it needs a name.

Comment: g(x) definitely doesn't have to be constant. Consider a dirac about theta

Comment: I found that this can be considered under "Product Type Gaussian Formulas": https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01934362

Which is nice and what I might just use, but I didn't see anything specific to this case.

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean for $f(x)$ to be near constant on the interval? It means that $f'(x) \approx 0$ on the interval. As such, here's a relatively naive improvement using integration by parts.

Let G be an anti-derivative of g (i.e. G' = g). By parts

$$\int g(x)f(x)dx \approx G(x)f(x)|_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta+\epsilon}$$

which is a slight improvement on the equation I gave. We can recover the original suggested equation as $f(\theta-\epsilon) \approx f(\theta+\epsilon) \approx f(\theta)$, thus

$$G(x)f(x)|_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta+\epsilon}\approx f(\theta)\left(G(x)|_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta+\epsilon}\right) = f(\theta) \int_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta+\epsilon} g(x)dx $$

which is just the proof for the "Constant Multiple Rule of Integration" and rather **boring**. I was hoping for a more robust, relatively general method. Please chime in if there are better methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally true, you need to refine what you mean by $\approx$ relative to $\epsilon$ and the derivative of $g$ otherwise pathological choices can be made. E.g. let $\theta = 0$, $f(x) = mx$ for some very small $m$ (i.e. "$m \approx 0$"), let $g(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^{100} m}x$, then one integral is $0$ but the other is probably pretty big (depending on $\epsilon$).

Comment: right so f'(x)g(x) must be near 0

Comment: $f'g$ must be near $0$... for what to happen? What do you want to be true, in precise terms? You want those integrals to be approximately equal, but what does approximate mean? Does it depend on $\epsilon$? Can $g$ be near $0$? When you say $f'g$ must be near zero, what does "near" mean in this case?

Comment: in analysis, "approximate" doesn't mean much on its own because the real numbers look/behave the same way at all scales. You may think you are considering a very small difference, but rest-assured I can always choose one that makes your original choice look gigantic unless you constrain my choices in some way.

Comment: in particular if you say $a \approx b$ somehow implies $c \approx d$, then you need to be very clear if "$\approx$" means the same thing in both statements, i.e. that they aren't on wildly different scales. Otherwise it isn't a very useful mathematical statement.